# An unspecified error occurred. Can't able to create new provision profile for appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Can't able to create new provision profile for app store. Showing alert with message "An unspecified error occurred. Please refresh and try again" I refreshed and tried a lot, but same error[image]

Comment: in the same boat, can't even create a production certificate without this warning happening. Tried different browsers and even a windows machine, same problem. Guess its a bug from apple.

Comment: actually, I tried some strange things but managed to get it working. I tried another browser IE 11 (yes IE !) and strangely it worked. Then I went back to chrome, logged out and logged back in, tried again and it worked.

Comment: It's possible with WWDC coming up, they were doing a systems elevation and it was temporarily not working.  @Britto Thomas, can you confirm it's working for you now?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem all day and this is how I solved it

1. Revoke your current certificate at developer.apple.com
2. Don't bother trying to renew the certificate via developer.apple.com, you'll just get the same crash as the person who posted this question
3. Open up Xcode
4. Select Preferences -> Accounts -> Apple IDs -> View Details
5. Press on the create button next to the iOS Distribution label
6. Go back to developer.apple.com and voila, your new certificate is there

Answer (score -1):

Check whether you have **admin** rights. My guess is that you're now only a **member** and are not allowed to do whatever you're trying to do.